# How to subvert NSTextView's "smart" copy & paste, which is adding unwanted whitespace?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextview

If I double-click on a word inside my NSTextField, it selects the entire word, which is good.  If I then paste that word elsewhere in the document, it adds a space before it pastes, which is unwanted for the style of application I'm making.  How can I turn this off?

Example:

```
apple->berry->cherry->banana
```

I double-click on "berry" and copy it to the clipboard.  I then place my cursor right after "banana" and type "->", then paste what I copied.  Instead of seeing:

```
apple->berry->cherry->banana->berry
```

I actually see:

```
apple->berry->cherry->banana-> berry
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

```
[textView setSmartInsertDeleteEnabled:NO];
```

Carry on :)